# Treating "probability thresholds" (classification problems) as a hyperparameter

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, roc, hyperparameter

I found this link over here :
https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html (section 13.8)

1. My understanding is that the probability threshold over here is essentially being treated as a hyperparameter, which is tuned for different values and ultimately cross validated. Is this a correct interpretation?
2. I am slightly confused as to why this code begins with taking a "training set" instead of using the whole data.

As explained here:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/38-regression-model-validation/157-cross-validation-essentials-in-r

It seems that when you use repeatedcv, there is no need hard split the data into training and test ... rather the whole data is periodically used for training and testing. Does this mean when doing gridsearchcv, if you choose "repeatedcv", you also don't hard split the data into training and test?

Thank you!

Comment: The first link is a long technical document. Why don't you describe what the "probability threshold" is directly in your question instead of making us go look for it "over here"?

Comment: @develarist sorry, ill do that right now

Comment: This seems to ask two questions: one about treating threshold as a hyperparameter and another about why a particular software implementation does not require data to be split into training and test sets. I recommend a separate question for each of these.